# Leaky bucket method with Haproxy - Rate limiting

Tags: haproxy

Nginx uses the leaky bucket method to limit request rate. [Nginx http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

It means that if I set a limit to 100 req/sec, and then I get flooded by 120 req/sec, 100 requests will be served normally but 20 requests will be served by a 503 error.

How can I setup this with Haproxy?

I read a lot of the documentation about **sc_http_req_rate** but since the rate is always 120 req/sec. I am always returning 503 errors.

```
frontend main
    bind *:80
    acl foo_limited_req sc_http_req_rate(0) ge 100
    http-request track-sc0 path table Abuse     # Set the URI as the key of the table
    use_backend bk1 if foo_limited_req
    default_backend web

backend web
    server web1 192.168.0.10

backend Abuse
    stick-table type string len 128 size 100K expire 30m store http_req_rate(1s)

backend bk1
     server listenerror 127.0.0.1:81

listen errorlistener
    bind 127.0.0.1:81
    mode http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/200-tuned.http
```

I want to serve the flow of 100 req/sec with *web* backend. And the 20 req/sec surplus with *bk1* backend.

Comment: You're on the right track. Maybe this blog is helpful? http://alex.mamchenkov.net/2017/05/17/haproxy-abuse-filtering-rate-limiting/

Comment: I do not want to reject any connection. My goal is to reply with a specific code to what is over the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Youll want to set the maxconn setting in your global settings to "X", which is your desired rate limit.

See below for an example of mine:

```
global
  log         127.0.0.1 syslog
  maxconn     1000
  user        haproxy
  group       haproxy
  daemon
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but maxconn defines the limit of current connections not the connection rate. And I am talking about request rate not connection rate.